# Find the probability that the passenger waits more than 10 min for the bus

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

Buses arrive at a bus stop at 15 min intervals starting at 7 am assume that a passenger arrives at the bus stop at random time X (given in minutes after 7 am ) with PDF

$$f_X(x) =
\begin{cases}
 \frac {x(60-x)}{36000},  & \text{if $ 0\le x \le 60 $} \\
0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

I have try to set everything as the following  :

$X$: time the passenger arrive at the bus stop

$Y$: the waiting time

Since I need the passenger to be waiting more than 10min  so I have $P(Y>10)$
With $P(15-X>10) = P(X<5)=P(X \le 4)= \int_{0}^{4} \frac {x(60-x)}{36000}dx=0.012=1.2$%$ $

I was wondering if that can be a viable solution and if for any reasons there's a new way to proceed please let me know.

Comment: $X < 5$ isn't equal to $X \le 4$.

Comment: Is it because of the continuous RV setting ?

Comment: Exactly. You also have to consider the idea suggested in Siong's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guide:

If someone has to wait for more than $10$ minutes, his corresponding arrival time in term of $x$ is

$$(0,5) \cup (15, 20) \cup (30, 35) \cup (45, 50)$$

Comment: Are you suggesting that I should be integration over those intervals ?

Comment: yup, there are multiple ways to wait for more than $10$ minutes.

Comment: Then how do you know when to stop ?

Comment: We know for sure you will reach within $1$ hour. I have listed all the possible time intervals.

Comment: @MahamadA.Kanouté that is a good question, and I believe the answer comes from the density function, which is non zero only in the first hour.

Comment: I see now that the key is on the pdf which has $0 \le x \le 60$ I will be more careful next time. Thanks guys !